# Максимальный прямоугольник в подграфике кусочно постоянной функции

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть задача.

> Дана последовательность N прямоугольников различной ширины и высоты (wi,hi). Прямоугольники расположены, начиная с точки (0, 0), на оси ОХ
> вплотную друг за другом (вправо). Требуется найти M - площадь
> максимального прямоугольника (параллельного осям координат), который
> можно вырезать из этой фигуры.

При n <= 8000 задача проходит, а при n <= 10**5 - нет. Вот код

```
inf = int(2e9+1)#барьеры для массива
n = int(input())
a = []#высоты для прямоугольников
w = []#ширина для прямоугольников
for i in range(n):#получаем значения.
    v,h= map(int,input().split())
    a.append(h)
    w.append(v)
a = [-inf] + a + [-inf]#добавляем барьеры
ans = [0] * (n+2)#список для ответов
st = [0]
l = []#список элементов левее i, которые меньше a[i]
r = []#список элементов правее i, которые меньше a[i]
rez = []
for i in range(1,n+2):#ищем кандидатов для r
    while int(a[st[-1]]) > int(a[i]):
        ans[st.pop()] = i-1   
    st.append(i)
for i in range(1,n+1):#добавляем их в ответ
    if ans[i] == 0:
        r.append(n)
    else:
        r.append(ans[i])

a = a[::-1]#разворачиваем массив, для того, чтобы найти элементы, левее i и <a[i]
ans = [0] * (n+2)
st = [0]
for i in range(1,n+2):
    while int(a[st[-1]]) > int(a[i]):
        ans[st.pop()] = i-1   
    st.append(i)
ans = ans[::-1]
for i in range(1,n+1):#добавляем их в ответ
    if ans[i] == n:
        l.append(-1)
    else:
        l.append((n-ans[i])-1)
        
rez = []
a = a[::-1]
a.pop(0)
a.pop()
pref = []
for i in range(len(l)):#считаем длины прямоугольников, которые влезают в границы l[i],r[i]
    #if l[i] == -1:
        #pref.append(sum(w[0:r[i]]))
        
    if r[i] == n:
        pref.append(sum(w[l[i]+1:]))
        
    else:
        pref.append(sum(w[l[i]+1:r[i]]))
      

for i in range(n):#выводим площади прямоугольников.
    rez.append(a[i]*pref[i])
print(max(rez))
```

Comment: Кст, каждый вызов `[::-1]` создает новую копию списка, уже тут можно подумать над оптимизацией. И еще, а не могли бы вы описать в комментарии к коду что где происходит?

Comment: Простите, а как вы вообще вводите n <= 10**5 элементов??   Да даже 8000 элементов? Просто инетерсно, на каких примерах вы свою программу отлаживали?

Comment: Стоит заменить все ```a = a[::-1]``` на ```a.reverse()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я "перевел" код [Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor) с JS на Python в этом вопросе, возможно вас устроит: [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152154/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/1152589#1152589)

Вот сам код:

```
def maxArea(rs):
    a = 0
    for i in range(len(rs)):
        r = rs[i]
        ai = r[0] * r[1] + back(rs, r[1], i) + forward(rs, r[1], i)
        a = max(a, ai)
    return a

def back(rs, h, idx):
    a = 0
    for j in range(idx-1, -1, -1):
        if rs[j][0] >= h:
            a += rs[j][0] * h
        else:
            break
    return a

def forward(rs, h, idx):
    a = 0
    for j in range(idx+1, len(rs)):
      if rs[j][1] >= h:
        a += rs[j][0] * h
      else:
        break
    return a

rs1 = [[4, 3], [2, 1], [2, 5]]
rs2 = [[4, 3], [2, 1], [3, 5]]

print(maxArea(rs1))
print(maxArea(rs2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо бы, если бы можно было пользоваться библиотекой `Numpy`. Но даже если нельзя, то для начала избавьтесь от всех `append` по возможности, сразу задав максимальный размер всем спискам, так же как вы делаете это в этой строке:

```
ans = [0] * (n+2)
```

То есть

```
l = [0] * n # или n + 2 или n * 2 смотря по ситуации
i = 0
```

И потом вместо

```
l.append(x)
```

Пишите

```
l[i] = x
i += 1
```

Должно работать быстрее. Но лучше бы использовать `Numpy`, там числовые массивы работают гораздо быстрее, чем списки `Python`.

И да, список l приведён в качестве примера, у вас там такого добра полно в коде, почти в каждом цикле можно сделать так же.

P.S. Провёл небольшой тест в Google Colab, ускорение от этого всего в 1.5 раза, мало. Списки Python очень медленные в любом случае.

Comment: Спасибо, но это решение не исправило проблемы.